# c# reference assignment not working as expected

Tags: c#, .net, oop, inheritance

so i wrote a simple timer class

```
public class ConsoleTimer : IDisposable
{
    private Stopwatch _watch;
    private IList _items;
    public object Count = "0";

    public ConsoleTimer(IList items) {
        _watch = new Stopwatch();
        _items = items;
        _watch.Start();
    }


    public void Dispose() {
        var c = Console.ForegroundColor;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        _watch.Stop();
        TimeSpan ts = _watch.Elapsed;
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} items in {1}m {2}s", _items != null ? _items.Count : Count, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds));
        Console.ForegroundColor = c;
    }
}
```

as you can see, i accept optional constructor parameter (IList) so that when that list changes during the course of my timer scope, i can automatically write out how many items (rows/records/entities etc) were added.

using it as follows:

```
        using (ConsoleTimer t = new ConsoleTimer(_values)) {
            _values = GetValues(filter);
        }
```

Even though _values has a 955 items, the Dispose method of my timer still sees _items as the value that was passed in the constructor (whether it be 0 or null)

is the _items = items assignment not a reference assignment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

But you're assigning a new reference to `_values` which won't be seen by `_items`! Better to say

```
foreach(var value in GetValues(filter)) {
    _values.Add(value);
}
```

Now you're modifying the original referent so that both `_values` and `_items` see the changes.

Answer (score 0):

_items = items; is a reference assignment. The problem is that you're pointing to two different objects.

```
    using (ConsoleTimer t = new ConsoleTimer(_values)) {  // _values points to collection1
        _values = GetValues(filter);                      // Now _values points to collection2
    }
```

Your ConsoleTimer instance still points to collection1. You want to do something like _values.Add() or _values.AddRange().

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have the IList, let's call it IList1.  Your `_values` references this instance.  When you pass `_values` to your constructor, your ConsoleTimer `_items` now is a reference to IList1, **not** `_values`.

Now you change `_values` so that *it* refereneces a new instance, call it IList2.  Your `_items` *still* references the IList1 instance, it doesn't follow `_values` in reference.